# Subtraction if an items matches in both dictionaries working wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and I want to subtract value of an item if found in both the dictionaries for which I am doing this:

My Code:

```
X = {'a':7, 'b':8,'c':9,'d':10}
Y = {'a':3, 'b':4,'c':9}
res = {}

for k,v in X.items():
    for m,n in Y.items():
        if k == m:
            res[k] = v-n
        else:
            res[k] = v
```

It is giving me output:

```
res = {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 0, 'd': 10}
```

whereas what I need is this:

```
res = {'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 0, 'd': 10}
```

How can I get that ? And also why the above code isn't working ?

Comment: You need to break the loop once the if statement ```if k==m:``` is executed. Add break below ```res[k] == v-n```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert `break` statement in 1st condition as below:

```
X = {'a':7, 'b':8,'c':9,'d':10}
Y = {'a':3, 'b':4,'c':9}
res = {}

for k,v in X.items():
    for m,n in Y.items():
        if k == m:
            res[k] = v-n
            break
        else:
            res[k] = v

print(res)
```

Comment: But why was it not `self-breaking`, Can you help me understand that ?

Comment: It's comparing every key-value of X with every key-value of Y as it is in nested `for` loop. When found the match you need to `break` the inner loop explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
{k:X.get(k,0)-Y.get(k,0) for k in X.keys()|Y.keys()}
# {'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 0, 'd': 10} -->Order will not be maintained
```